# Como colocar imagem e texto ao lado com FlexBox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Eae galera estou com dificuldade de posicionar a imagem e o texto AO LADO  da imagem. Ja tentei tabela mas nao fica responsivo. Tentei ul/li e não consigo posicionar. Estou utilizando FlexBox. Alguma sugestão?.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
     <title>About Us</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style3.css">
     <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/logo.png">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arimo" rel="stylesheet">
       <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
        
    <body>
        <section class="bg">
            <div class="auutor">
                <h1>The Author</h1>
            </div>
            <ul class="fuckk">
                <li>
                    <img src="images/1313.png"/>
                    <h1>Roft Salem Throme</h1>
                    <p>But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain.</p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tem como tornar mais claro que devia ficar ao lado do que ? No seu exemplo tem 4 etiquetas com conteúdo, `h1`, `p`, `h1`, `img`. Quais deviam ficar ao lado de quais?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a propriedade `display : flex` na sua `li` envolvendo o titulo `h1` e o paragrafo `p` em uma `div`, como assim:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
     <title>About Us</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style3.css">
     <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/logo.png">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arimo" rel="stylesheet">
       <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,700" rel="stylesheet">

        <style type="text/css">
         li {
          list-style-type: none;
         }

            .conteudo {
                display: flex;
            }

            h1 {
             text-align: center;
            }

            li img {
                width : 20%;
                height: 20%;
                vertical-align: middle;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
        
    <body>
        <section class="bg">
            <div class="auutor">
                <h1>The Author</h1>
            </div>
            <ul class="fuckk">
                <li>
                 <h1>Roft Salem Throme</h1>
                    <div class="conteudo">
                     <img src="https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/help-icon-26.png"/>
                        <p>But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain.</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nao funcionou , o meu h1 fica do lado da imagem nao consigo centraliza-lo.o p a mesma coisa fica em cima e n consigo deixa-lo no meio tambem. sad :(

Comment: Editei o código para que o h1 fique em cima e centralizado, dá uma olhada!